# Using OSRM with Langchain

Tags: language-model, chatbot, open-source

I am trying to develop a chatbot using Langchain, to give me a routing option between 2 points on a custom map data. I am using free APIs from Huggingface for embedding and Ollama model for the question answering model.

If I need to include a way to display or maybe output the route between 2 places on a custom data using langchain. Is it possible to call osrm API within langchain and display some result?